# Show a form when another form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, events

On the click of a button (that's in the main form), I show a (second) form that does some parsing (decompress, extract, get information, etc) of an archive file. After this process is done, I close the second (parsing) form and show another (third) form that contains the parsed information from the archive.

Click callback looks like this:

```
private void ParseInputBackupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form PBF = new ParseBackupForm();
    Form CBF = new CreateBackupForm();
    PBF.FormClosed += delegate
    {
        CBF.ShowDialog();
    };
    PBF.ShowDialog();
}
```

and the second form:

```
private void ParseBackupForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
    {

        // parse and update form

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            this.Close();
        });

    }).Start();
}
```

The problem is when the third form (`CreateBackupForm`) appears, the second form (`ParseBackupForm`) doesn't close. They both appear. If I don't show the third form, the second form closes.

[image: screenshot of the forms]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are calling `ShowDialog` on both windows, couldn't you just call them one after the other?

i.e.

```
PBF.ShowDialog();
CBF.ShowDialog();
```

The second call will not be made until the PBG dialog has closed.

Edit: The reason why the second form doesn't close is that the you are subscribing to an event raised by the form as it closes, then within that delegate calling `ShowDialog` which blocks the form from actually closing.

Comment: Aha, this worked. The solution is so simple that I feel silly now :)

Comment: Happens to us all.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember `.ShowDialog()` is a blocking method, so would stop the other form from completing its close method until that form is also closed?

Pretty sure you can use `.Show()` to just make a form visible without blocking?

Comment: `CBF.Show()` kind of worked, but I can switch between the forms (main and the third). This is not desirable. Main form should be inaccessable when another form is active/shown. Is there a way to make the third form (`CBF`) act like a dialog although it's called with `Show()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could BeginInvoke the call of `CBF.ShowDialog();`, thus not blocking the completion of the FormClosed callback method and the closing of the `PBF` form.